# How to reprocess DLT messages after the underlying issues get fixed?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a `KafkaListener` configured as a `RetryableTopic` to retry a processing a failure-inducing data a few times before sending it to `DLT`, e.g:

```
@KafkaListener(
    groupId = "\${kafka.stuff.groupId}",
    topics = ["\${kafka.stuff.topic}"],
    concurrency = "\${kafka.stuff.concurrency}",
    autoStartup = "\${kafka.stuff.auto-start:true}"
)
@RetryableTopic(
    attempts = "#{'\${kafka.stuff.attempts}'}",
    backoff = Backoff(
        delayExpression = "\${kafka.stuff.backoff.delay}",
        multiplierExpression = "\${kafka.stuff.backoff.multiplier}"
    ),
    autoCreateTopics = "#{'\${kafka.stuff.auto-create}'}",
    topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
    dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR
)
fun consumeStuff(
    @Payload stuff: StuffDto,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) key: String,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) partition: Int
) = runBlocking {
    log.info("{} stuff received {}", LogSymbols.START_SYMBOL, key)
    process(stuff, key)
}
```

After it arrives in the DLT, I don't want it to be reprocessed automatically before having a fix for the failure's cause - on the other hand, once the fix is deployed I do want to reprocess these messages, therefore my first thought was to have another listener for this purpose disabled by default:

```
@KafkaListener(
    groupId = "\${kafka.stuff.groupId}",
    topics = ["\${kafka.stuff.topic}-dlt"],
    concurrency = "\${kafka.stuff.dlt.concurrency}",
    autoStartup = "\${kafka.stuff.dlt.auto-start:false}" //disabled by default -> enable it on-demand
)
fun processStuffInDlt(
    @Payload stuff: StuffDto,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) key: String,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) partition: Int
) = runBlocking {
    log.info("{} Re-process stuff {} from DLT", LogSymbols.START_SYMBOL, key)
    process(stuff, key)
}
```

But I can foresee at least two problems with this approach:

- After the messages get reprocessed, `processStuffInDlt` will remain active, thereby reprocessing the upcoming issues - Is it possible to enable/disable this listener on-demand without the need for a new deployment?
- If one of the messages is still inducing the problem, `processStuffInDlt` will attempt to reprocess it a few times without success and then acknowledge the message, meaning that it won't attempt to reprocess it in a later date - Is it possible to prevent this ack upon failure?

A broader question: Are there a better approaches to implement the ability to reprocess DLT failure-inducing messages in upcoming deployments?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect when the DLT container goes idle, by setting the `idleEventInterval` and adding an event listener.

When the container goes idle, stop the container.

Do not use the thread that invokes the event listener to stop the container, run the `stop()` on a thread, e.g. from a `TaskExecutor`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

It might be a good idea to stop the main (and retry) listener containers while processing DLT records.

Use the `ListenerContainerRegistry` bean to start/stop containers.

To avoid acking failed records in the DLT, set the error handler's back off to retry infinitely `Long.MAX_VALUE`, or configure the recoverer to stop the container when retries are exhausted (call a `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Took Gary Russell's advice on using the container beans for start/stop and error handlers. Took me a bit to go over all of this, so I'm posting the details.

First, I created this class to replace `processStuffInDlt`:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.time.Duration



@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StuffListenerContainer.Config::class)
class StuffListenerContainer(
    private val config: Config,
    private val stuffService: StuffService,
) {
    companion object {
        private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka.stuff")
    data class Config(
        val topic: String,
        val groupId: String
    )

    @Bean
    fun dltProcessor(consumerFactory: ConsumerFactory<String, StuffDto>):
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, StuffDto> {

        val containerProps = ContainerProperties(config.topic + "-dlt")

        containerProps.setGroupId(config.groupId)

        //add listener to reprocess 
        containerProps.messageListener =
            MessageListener { message: ConsumerRecord<String, StuffDto> ->
                run {
                    log.info("DLT Re-process stuff ${message.key()} from DLT")
                    stuffService.process(message.value(), message.key())
                }
            }

        containerProps.consumerStartTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(5)

        val container = KafkaMessageListenerContainer(
            consumerFactory,
            containerProps
        )
        //container stops if failure-inducing message
        container.commonErrorHandler = CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler() 

        container.isAutoStartup = false

        return container
    }


}
```

This allows me to have this rest controller start/stop containers on-demand:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stuff/reprocess")
class ReprocessStuffController(
    private val dltProcessor: KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, StuffDto>
) {

    @GetMapping("/running")
    fun isRunning(): ResponseEntity<Boolean> {
        return ResponseEntity(
            dltProcessor.isRunning,
            HttpStatus.OK
        )
    }

    @PostMapping("/start")
    fun start() {
        dltProcessor.start()
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop")
    fun stop() {
        dltProcessor.stop()
    }

    @PostMapping("/pause")
    fun pause() {
        dltProcessor.pause()
    }

    @PostMapping("/resume")
    fun resume() {
        dltProcessor.resume()
    }

}
```

Finally, `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler`  stops the container upon error preventing the ack -> next deploy it will attempt to reprocess the message again